# Get all records by category NestJs + MongoDB + Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nest, nestjs

I'm using NestJs + MongoDB + Mongoose, and I would like to get all the records in MongoDB with the record that I send by parameter, but I'm not getting it, I'm a beginner. How could I get all records from the same category?
I send the category ID in the request, but I don't receive all the records for that category, could you help me?

I need this:

GET /users/food
and return this:

{
  "password": "123",
  "name": "Brian",
  "adress": "",
  "email": "a@a",
  "category": "food",
  "cpfOrCnpj": "string"
},

{
  "password": "123",
  "name": "Margo",
  "adress": "",
  "email": "a@a",
  "category": "food",
  "cpfOrCnpj": "string"
}

my code:

my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { User } from './user.model';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(@InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: Model<User>) {}

  async create(doc: User) {
    //Ok
    const result = await new this.userModel(doc).save();
    return result.id;
  }

  async find(id: string) {
    return await this.userModel.findById(id).exec();
  }


  async update(user: User) {
    //Test
    return await this.userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(user);
  }

}
```

my controller:

```
import { Body, Controller, Get, Param, Post, Put } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { User } from './user.model';

@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
  constructor(private service: UserService) {}

  @Get(':id')
    async find(@Param('category') id: string) {
    return this.service.find(id);
  }

  @Post('create')
  create(@Body() user: User) {
    return this.service.create(user);
  }

  @Put('update')
  update(@Body() user: User) {
    return this.service.update(user);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function

```
  find(id: string) {
    return this.userModel.findById(id).exec();
  }
```

you're searching by the `_id`, `findById` method is used to filter by the `_id` of the document

I think `category` is not the `_id` of your document here

so, you need to use the normal `find` method, and pass an object to it

```
  find(id: string) { // id is not _id here, I suggest you to name it category instead 
    return this.userModel.find({ category: id }).exec();
  }
```

> Note, you don't need the async/await here, as you are returning the promise itself

hope it helps